# HBase Java Api gets stuck at put()

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I have been connecting to my HBase and executing commands quite normally with my Java application. But lately, once I get a table this way :

```
Table table = hbconnection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(DOC_TABLE_NAME));
```

it then gets stuck at commands like this one :

```
table.put(myput);
```

I don't get an exception. The application doesn't terminate. It just hangs there...

When I look at Hbase output in the CLI, I notice this part :

```
2015-10-20 15:01:53,207 INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1):] server.PrepRequestProcessor: Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x150855715570000 type:create cxid:0xd57 zxid:0x62e txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase/namespace/hbase Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /hbase/namespace/hbase
2015-10-20 15:01:53,217 INFO  [Greg:52905.activeMasterManager] master.HMaster: Master has completed initialization

2015-10-20 15:01:53,220 INFO  [greg:52905.activeMasterManager] quotas.MasterQuotaManager: Quota support disabled
2015-10-20 15:02:10,001 INFO  [SessionTracker] server.ZooKeeperServer: Expiring session 0x1508540d00a0009, timeout of 40000ms exceeded
2015-10-20 15:02:10,002 INFO  [SessionTracker] server.ZooKeeperServer: Expiring session 0x1508540d00a0008, timeout of 40000ms exceeded
2015-10-20 15:02:10,005 INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1):] server.PrepRequestProcessor: Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x1508540d00a0009
2015-10-20 15:02:10,007 INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1):] server.PrepRequestProcessor: Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x1508540d00a0008
2015-10-20 15:06:48,610 INFO  [LruBlockCacheStatsExecutor] hfile.LruBlockCache: totalSize=1.67 MB, freeSize=1.58 GB, max=1.58 GB, blockCount=4, accesses=17, hits=13, hitRatio=76.47%, , cachingAccesses=17, cachingHits=13, cachingHitsRatio=76.47%, evictions=29, evicted=0, evictedPerRun=0.0
2015-10-20 15:06:58,791 INFO  [greg,52936,1445346099888_ChoreService_1] regionserver.HRegionServer: greg,52936,1445346099888-MemstoreFlusherChore requesting flush for region hbase:meta,,1.1588230740 after a delay of 20679
2015-10-20 15:07:08,790 INFO  [greg,52936,1445346099888_ChoreService_1] regionserver.HRegionServer: greg,52936,1445346099888-MemstoreFlusherChore requesting flush for region hbase:meta,,1.1588230740 after a delay of 6649
2015-10-20 15:07:18,790 INFO  [greg,52936,1445346099888_ChoreService_1] regionserver.HRegionServer: greg,52936,1445346099888-MemstoreFlusherChore requesting flush for region hbase:meta,,1.1588230740 after a delay of 18558
2015-10-20 15:07:19,481 INFO  [MemStoreFlusher.0] regionserver.HRegion: Started memstore flush for hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, current region memstore size 2.79 KB, and 1/1 column families' memstores are being flushed.
2015-10-20 15:07:19,643 INFO  [MemStoreFlusher.0] regionserver.DefaultStoreFlusher: Flushed, sequenceid=332, memsize=2.8 K, hasBloomFilter=false, into tmp file file:/C:/Users/greg/AppData/Local/Temp/hbase-greg/hbase/data/hbase/meta/1588230740/.tmp/edcebd7b3e8841de931094a5f97f7d1b
2015-10-20 15:07:19,702 INFO  [MemStoreFlusher.0] regionserver.HStore: Added file:/C:/Users/greg/AppData/Local/Temp/hbase-greg/hbase/data/hbase/meta/1588230740/info/edcebd7b3e8841de931094a5f97f7d1b, entries=12, sequenceid=332, filesize=6.0 K
2015-10-20 15:07:19,705 INFO  [MemStoreFlusher.0] regionserver.HRegion: Finished memstore flush of ~2.79 KB/2856, currentsize=0 B/0 for region hbase:meta,,1.1588230740 in 224ms, sequenceid=332, compaction requested=false
2015-10-20 15:11:48,609 INFO  [LruBlockCacheStatsExecutor] hfile.LruBlockCache: totalSize=1.67 MB, freeSize=1.58 GB, max=1.58 GB, blockCount=4, accesses=19, hits=15, hitRatio=78.95%, , cachingAccesses=19, cachingHits=15, cachingHitsRatio=78.95%, evictions=59, evicted=0, evictedPerRun=0.0
```

I'm running on windows and JDK 1.8.
My hbase-site config is empty.
My app's classpath is the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Greg/Documents/Tools/hbase-1.1.2-bin/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Greg/Documents/Tools/hbase-1.1.2-bin/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Greg/Documents/Tools/hbase-1.1.2-bin/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Greg/Documents/Tools/hbase-1.1.2-bin/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Greg/Documents/Tools/hbase-1.1.2-bin/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Greg/Documents/Tools/hbase-1.1.2-bin/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Greg/Documents/Tools/hbase-1.1.2-bin/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Greg/Documents/Tools/hbase-1.1.2-bin/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Greg/Documents/Tools/hbase-1.1.2-bin/lib/hadoop-client-2.5.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Greg/Documents/Tools/hbase-1.1.2-bin/lib/hadoop-common-2.5.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Greg/Documents/Tools/hbase-1.1.2-bin/lib/hbase-client-1.1.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Greg/Documents/Tools/hbase-1.1.2-bin/lib/hbase-common-1.1.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Greg/Documents/Tools/hbase-1.1.2-bin/lib/guava-12.0.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Greg/Documents/Tools/hbase-1.1.2-bin/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Greg/Documents/Tools/hbase-1.1.2-bin/lib/hadoop-hdfs-2.5.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Greg/Documents/Tools/hbase-1.1.2-bin/lib/hadoop-auth-2.5.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Greg/Documents/Tools/hbase-1.1.2-bin/lib/hbase-annotations-1.1.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Greg/Documents/Tools/hbase-1.1.2-bin/lib/hbase-protocol-1.1.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Greg/Documents/Tools/hbase-1.1.2-bin/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Greg/Documents/Tools/hbase-1.1.2-bin/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Greg/Documents/Tools/hbase-1.1.2-bin/lib/netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Greg/Documents/Tools/hbase-1.1.2-bin/lib/commons-codec-1.9.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Greg/Documents/Tools/tika-core-1.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Greg/Documents/Tools/tika-parsers-1.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Greg/Documents/Tools/pdfbox-app-1.8.10.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

How can I fix this and get HBase responsive again?
Thank you for your help.

---

EDIT

I tried deleting the tmp data in **C:\Users\greg\AppData\Local\Temp**
as well as the **data** and **zookeeper** folders in my project and now Hbase doesn't even start.

```
2015-10-20 15:51:27,022 INFO  [RS:0;greg:54045-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2015-10-20 15:51:27,213 INFO  [main-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2015-10-20 15:51:28,026 WARN  [RS:0;greg:54045-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x150858481600003 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
2015-10-20 15:51:28,217 WARN  [main-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x150858481600001 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
```

Comment: do you dispose of your tables properly?  are you re-using your connections?

Comment: This command is at the very beginning of my function.After this "put" (that doesn't seem to work), I do close my connections

Comment: hbase maintains information in ZK.  if you've nuked ZK data you'll have to restart hbase.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your session ended up in inconsistent state leaving some meta data in ZooKeeper (that's the first error you got), maybe you could have solved that error by cleaning ZooKeeper yourself using [ZooKeeper client](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.3/zookeeperStarted.html#sc_ConnectingToZooKeeper) and cleaning HBase entries there and restarting HBase.

However now that you can not even start HBase, I would suggest to [download](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/zookeeper/) and start your own ZooKeeper server at the same address (127.0.0.1:2181) and try to start HBase again. If that works then it means you need to look into fixing HBase ZooKeeper connection properly. I am not very familiar with HBase but [this](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/zookeeper.html#d1865e11323) might be a good place to start.